# How can I use two hdri for sphere and for environment of scene (world)

Tags: hdri

It should be something like this (one on top, other on bottom (something about 180 degree) (for both, for sphere and scene environment (world))
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it comes down to this, you need slightly different settings for *Object* and *World*. I'm sorry but I have no HDRI where the horizon is in the center or slightly below the image, so in my example you will still see some landscape - but the setup works. Maybe you have a better HDRI.

For both *Object* and *World* you use *Generated* coordinates. For the sphere this means, the projection method in the *Image Texture* node has to be set to *Sphere* instead of the default *Flat*. The *Environment Texture* for the background can use the default *Equirectangular*.

Then you need a *Vector Rotate* node to rotate the coordinates for one of the textures. For both the *Axis* should be (1, 0, 0) and the *Angle* 180°. However the *Center* needs to be (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) for the sphere but for the world (0, 0, 0). If you wonder why I don't use the *Mapping* node for rotating the vectors by setting *Scale* Z = -1, this works for the world, but not the sphere, so I simply used *Vector Rotate* on both.

Next is a *Separate XYZ* node from which the Z output is plugged into a *Color Ramp*. This is to make the transition between the original and the rotated texture. For the *Object*, black and white should be around the center (0.5) of the color range, while the *World* needs them on the left side towards 0.

The original and the rotated coordinates each go into the *Vector* input of two texture nodes, both with the same image (although you could of course mix two different images as well). Their output goes into a *Mix Color* node, the rotated at the top and the original at the bottom. The mix factor is the *Color Ramp* output.

[image: mixing flipped textures]

And the result is this - as I said, unfortunately I had no HDRI where the horizon is low enough. Of course you could use a *Mapping* node to transform the texture up and down, but then you will have the same problem with stretching and distortion like mentioned in my answer to your other question.

[image: resulting sphere and sky]